# Не меняются стили при hover

Tags: html, css

Вообще не понимаю что делаю не так, почему не могу убрать подчеркивание у надписи? что нужно сделать? как правильно оформить css?

```css
.blog-flex-item {
  width: 370px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #eaeaea;
  height: 230px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.blog-flex-item__image {
  width: 159px;
  height: 130px;
}

.blog-flex-item__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-flex-item__title {
  color: #374049;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blog-flex-item:hover .blog-flex-item__title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="blog_link" href="#">
    <div class="blog-flex-item">
      <div class="blog-flex-item__image"><img src="http://www.youloveit.ru/uploads/gallery/main/162/pikachu.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="blog-flex-item__title">текст</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-decoration: none;` задавайте ссылке, а не div'у. То есть элементу с классом `blog_link`.

Comment: @Pyramidhead так тоже не срабатывает, я так уже пробовал и только что попробовал снова. Я такое сотню раз делал, что сейчас не так вообще ума не приложу, не выспался чтоли, не понимаю

Comment: все, разобрался

Comment: Смотрите в консоли. Скорее всего, какое-то другое правило перебивает эти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.blog-flex-item {
  width: 370px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #eaeaea;
  height: 230px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.blog-flex-item__image {
  width: 159px;
  height: 130px;
}

.blog-flex-item__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-flex-item__title {
  color: #374049;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blog-flex-item:hover .blog-flex-item__title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

/* Вот это надо было сделать */
.blog_link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="blog_link" href="#">
    <div class="blog-flex-item">
      <div class="blog-flex-item__image"><img src="http://www.youloveit.ru/uploads/gallery/main/162/pikachu.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="blog-flex-item__title">текст</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```